# How to specify differing column widths for child columns?

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a table where width of last 3 columns don't change by the values which i set, here is how it looks like in picture:
Programavimo darbas row's last columns size should be one 71 second 11 and last 17. But they are not.
[image]

What am i doing wrong, they all are the same even if their sizes are different. Ive tried putting width into style but still the same. Help please! And here is my html code:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" border="0" class="tbl">
    <th style="width: 10%;"><?php echo $AppUI->_('Task type'); ?></th>
    <th style="width: 10%;"><?php echo $AppUI->_('Task quantity'); ?></th><!--Užduočių kiekis-->
    <th style="width: 10%;"><?php echo $AppUI->_('All time'); ?></th><!--Visas laikas-->
    <th style="width: 10%;"><?php echo $AppUI->_('Average'); ?></th><!--Visas laikas--> 
    <th colspan="3" style="width: 60%;"><?php echo $AppUI->_('In time/Due time'); ?></th><!--Vidurkis per užduotį-->

<?php
    if (!empty($taskqu)) {
        foreach ($taskqu as $key => $value) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "
            <td>{$task_types[$key]}</td>
            <td>{$taskqu[$key]['viso_tasku']}</td>
            <td>{$taskqu[$key]['viso_valandu']}</td>
            <td>{$taskqu[$key]['vidurkis']}</td>
            <td style='width: {$taskqu[$key]['viso_pabaigti']}%; background: springgreen; text-align: center;'>comp</td>
            <td style='width: {$taskqu[$key]['laiku']}%; background: aquamarine; text-align: center;'>laik</td>
            <td style='width: {$taskqu[$key]['veluojama']}%; background: tomato; text-align: center;'>vel</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

?>
</table>
```

Comment: What values are you trying to edit and why, could you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: as you can see my td's of last column width's, should be different from others but they are all the same

Comment: You cannot have differing column widths within the same table definition for the same nth column.

What you need to do is insert a sub-table within to define a new structure.

Comment: I need that tds with would be different in last column not columns.

Comment: Leave the fifth column defined in your table headers as a single column. Within each `TD` for that column, define a new table, where you can freely set different column widths.

Comment: I guess you missed the closing bracket of the _if_ statement..

Comment: If table column widths would vary across rows then it wouldn't be a table anymore, just a random collection of boxes. The "special" thing about a table is exactly its row/column behaviour.

Comment: @technophyle its not the all code just a part.

Comment: Why do you need the last 3 columns to be differing widths - would it not look like a mess?

Comment: oh ok.. then you could put an ellipsis there..

Comment: You could suggest me or show other ways so it would look with different sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hIs this what you are trying to achieve with your last few columns?

```html
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <thead>
        <th style="width:10%;">th1</th>
        <th style="width:10%;">th2</th>
        <th style="width:10%;">th3</th>
        <th style="width:10%;">th4</th>
        <th style="width:60%;">th5</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>td1</td>
            <td>td2</td>
            <td>td3</td>
            <td>td4</td>
            <td>
                <table width="100%" border="1" style="background-color:yellow;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:71%;">1</td>
                        <td style="width:11%;">2</td>
                        <td style="width:17%;">3</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>td1</td>
            <td>td2</td>
            <td>td3</td>
            <td>td4</td>
            <td>
                <table width="100%" border="1" style="background-color:green;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:61%;">1</td>
                        <td style="width:6%;">2</td>
                        <td style="width:32%;">3</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>td1</td>
            <td>td2</td>
            <td>td3</td>
            <td>td4</td>
            <td>
                <table width="100%" border="1" style="background-color:red;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:18%;">1</td>
                        <td style="width:11%;">2</td>
                        <td style="width:71%;">3</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues that might cause:

1. There's no `<tr>` tag after the `<table>` tag.
2. You may use `<col>` tags in the way described below.

**Columns**

Try using `<col>` tags:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" border="0" class="tbl">
  <col width="10%">
  <col width="10%">
  <col width="10%">
  <col width="10%">
  <col width="60%">
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 10%;"><?php echo $AppUI->_('Task type'); ?></th>
    <th style="width: 10%;"><?php echo $AppUI->_('Task quantity'); ?></th><!--Užduočių kiekis-->
    <th style="width: 10%;"><?php echo $AppUI->_('All time'); ?></th><!--Visas laikas-->
    <th style="width: 10%;"><?php echo $AppUI->_('Average'); ?></th><!--Visas laikas--> 
    <th colspan="3" style="width: 60%;"><?php echo $AppUI->_('In time/Due time'); ?></th><!--Vidurkis per užduotį-->
  </tr>
  <!-- -->
</table>
```